# How to convert date to String with 'ddmmyy' format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date

I'd like to convert a date to a string as 'mmddyy' in SQL Server. What I'm looking for is essentially what Excel can do with TEXT.

Thanks

Comment: Check convert function, maybe the 101 format is what you are looking for, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version (2012 and up), FORMAT would do the trick.

```
SELECT  FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddMMyy');
```

Comment: FORMAT() is from version SQL Server 2012 and up.

Comment: Also, note the difference between the answer's "ddMMyy" and the question's "ddmmyy". Lowercase "mm" is minutes - and I doubt this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get that formatted date. You can use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. You can use it like below :

```
select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 5),'-','')
```

Here is the [SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b28da/1568)

Comment: The "magic number 5" is the Italian date format (dd-mm-yy). But then, you knew that already, right ?

Comment: Yes I knew that!